# Scraping the table from multi pages in the website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm newbie in web scraping and below is my code and I wanted to **scrape** the table from all the pages (or just first 5 pages should be enough).

Website = https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_midover&o=ticker&r=0

not sure what can I do next in order to get all these 3 pages table in one table. Please help me, thanks a lot :)

I had tried to run this code but yet there is no table come out from this code

```
require(dplyr)
require(rvest)

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

url_base <- "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_midover&o=ticker&r="

tbl.clactions <- data.frame(
  "Ticker" = character(0),"Company" = character(0),
  "Sector" = character(0),"Industry" = character(0),
  "Country" = character(0),"Market.Cap" = character(0),
  "P/E" = character(0),"ROA" = character(0),
  "ROE" = character(0),"Price" = character(0),
  "Change" = character(0),"Volume" = character(0)
)

page <- c(0,21,41)

for (i in page) { 
  url <- paste0(url_base, i)
  tbl.page <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="screener-content"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table') %>%
    html_table()
}
```

Seems like there is no error for this code

Comment: This is explicitly disallowed by that site's policies: https://finviz.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one-way to do it

```
#Generate all the url's from where we need to extract the data
url_base <- paste0("https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_midover&o=ticker&r=", c(0,21,41))


library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

#Extract the table from each URL and bind them into one table
purrr::map_df(url_base, ~.x %>%
       read_html() %>%
       html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
      .[[10]] %>%
       setNames(as.character(.[1,])) %>%
       slice(-1))

#   No. Ticker                                         Company           Sector
#1    1      A                      Agilent Technologies, Inc.       Healthcare
#2    2     AA                               Alcoa Corporation  Basic Materials
#3    3   AABA                                     Altaba Inc.        Financial
#4    4    AAL                    American Airlines Group Inc.         Services
#5    5    AAN                                   Aaron's, Inc.         Services
#6    6   AAON                                      AAON, Inc. Industrial Goods
#....
```

Comment: Hello, this code works well for me! Thank you so much for the help as I struggled for few days already! May I clarify some of the detail from you? Actually what does    "~.x" ,  ".[[10]]"  ,  "as.character(.[1,])"  and  "slice(-1)"   mean? These 4 things carry their own specific meaning right? This is my weakness in coding and if you can suggest me for some books or website to learn all these coding start from beginner I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Kasen As in your `for` loop how you have `for (i in page)`, `.x` is the same here instead of `i`. There are multiple tables on every page and by doing `.[[10]]` we select the 10th table as that's what we need. While extracting data the column names were not read correctly, they were instead read as rows. So by doing `setNames(as.character(.[1,]))` we are assigning the first row as column name and since 1st row is column name we remove it from actual data doing `slice(-1)`

Comment: @Kasen I checked it manually. Since all of the pages have the same structure it is present at 10th table in every page.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! My one last question is how to know the table I want is the 10th table? Where should I add  "Sys.sleep(5)" for some pausing?

Comment: @Kasen To add some delay you can do `purrr::map_df(url_base, ~{
  Sys.sleep(5);
  .x %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table(fill = TRUE) %>%
    .[[10]] %>%
    setNames(as.character(.[1,])) %>%
    slice(-1)
    })`. As far as manually checking is concerned I did it for one page by doing `url_base[1] %>%
read_html() %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) 
` and then saw at what position was the table present.

Comment: Okayy, thanks a lot! You really helped me a lot! Have a great day! :)